# How to set Bitmap on ImageView using library Volley

Tags: android, bitmap, android-volley

I'm trying to use the library to perform volley download images from my server. 
In my activity I add items dynamically and then realize the exchange of image at runtime.

Below is the code of the attempt to get the picture:

```
public void updateThumbnails(ArrayList<Book> arrBook,ArrayList<View> arrView){
if(arrBook.size()<= 0){
    return;
}
if(arrView.size() <= 0){
    return;
}
int intBooks = arrView.size();
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
for(int intIndex = 0; intIndex < intBooks; intIndex++){
    View _view = arrView.get(intIndex);
    final View _viewLoader = _view;
    imageLoader.get(Const.START_REQUEST_BOOK_IMAGE + arrBook.get(intIndex).getId().toString() + ".jpg", new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer imageContainer, boolean b) {
            ImageView imgBook = (ImageView) _viewLoader.findViewById(R.id.img_book);
            animationChangeImage(imageContainer.getBitmap(),imgBook);
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

        }
    });
    TextView txtTitleBook = (TextView) _view.findViewById(R.id.name_book);
    txtTitleBook.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that the returned bitmap (`imageContainer.getBitmap()`) isn't null before going ahead and assigning it.
Try and adding log prints to see if you're getting errors or a null bitmap, which could mean you're performing a bad request or server error, or perhaps the fault is in the `animationChangeImage` method if the bitmap is received successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the ImageRequest class? For example:

```
ImageRequest irq = new ImageRequest(imgUrl, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
        imView.setImageBitmap(response);

    }
}, 0, 0, null, null);
```